# json_encode replaces spaces with carriage return

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a php script that execute a mysql query and return the result in json_encode format but there is a problem. It seems that json replaces space with carriage return.

This is my json encode response

```
[
    {
        "codice": "1",
        "messaggio": "Leghe utente",
        "output": [
            {
                "ID_LEGA": "28",
                "PORTIERI": "3",
                "DIFENSORI": "8",
                "CENTROCAMPISTI": "8",
                "ATTACCANTI": "6",
                "SCAMBI": "5",
                "OBBLIGO_ROSA": "1",
                "CALC_DUPLICATI": "0",
                "MERCATO_LIBERO": "0",
                "PARTECIPANTI": "10",
                "NOME": "Fantantonio Club 2013/2014",
                "CREDITI_INIZIALI": "500",
                "SOSTITUZIONI": "3",
                "POR_PANCHINA": "1",
                "DIF_PANCHINA": "2",
                "CEN_PANCHINA": "2",
                "ATT_PANCHINA": "2",
                "CAMBIO_MODULO": "1",
                "PORTIERE_IMBATTUTO": "0.0",
                "POR_MODIFICATORE": "0",
                "DIF_MODIFICATORE": "1",
                "CEN_MODIFICATORE": "0",
                "ATT_MODIFICATORE": "0",
                "SOGLIA_GOL": "66",
                "MINUTI_FORMAZIONE": "15",
                "FORMAZIONE_UNICA": "0"
            },
            {
                "ID_LEGA": "29",
                "PORTIERI": "3",
                "DIFENSORI": "8",
                "CENTROCAMPISTI": "8",
                "ATTACCANTI": "6",
                "SCAMBI": "5",
                "OBBLIGO_ROSA": "1",
                "CALC_DUPLICATI": "0",
                "MERCATO_LIBERO": "0",
                "PARTECIPANTI": "2",
                "NOME": "Lega di Esempio",
                "CREDITI_INIZIALI": "500",
                "SOSTITUZIONI": "3",
                "POR_PANCHINA": "1",
                "DIF_PANCHINA": "2",
                "CEN_PANCHINA": "2",
                "ATT_PANCHINA": "2",
                "CAMBIO_MODULO": "0",
                "PORTIERE_IMBATTUTO": "0.0",
                "POR_MODIFICATORE": "0",
                "DIF_MODIFICATORE": "0",
                "CEN_MODIFICATORE": "0",
                "ATT_MODIFICATORE": "0",
                "SOGLIA_GOL": "66",
                "MINUTI_FORMAZIONE": "15",
                "FORMAZIONE_UNICA": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Why, for example, json insert a carriage return between "Lega di" and "Esempio". In my db table there is not a carriage return.

Why?

Comment: If it were replacing spaces with carriage returns wouldn't "Lega di Esempio" become "Lega\rdi\rEsempio" ?

Comment: Your JSON is perfectly fine. It even validated at jsonlint.com